# cancelling a vote after a while

Tags: support, voting

I upvoted a question that looked promising but the questioner just abandoned the question not giving any more info and nobody could answer it because they abandoned it. I'd like to remove the 1 vote and if anything, downvote it. But I can't even remove the upvote.

It says I voted on it on jun 16th and the vote is locked. I think I probably tried weeks ago too but no luck.  Where is the sense in that?

[wget -nd (--no-directories) option not working as expected](https://superuser.com/questions/297965/wget-nd-no-directories-option-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6250/133693

Answer (score 2):

Votes are "locked in" after 5 minutes (assuming the final state is up or down).

Votes can only be changed after 5 minutes when the underlying post is changed (i.e. edited) in some way.

Comment: Does that mean that once @barlop gets 100 more rep (hits 2000) he can edit the Question in some way and then remove his upvote?

Comment: @spiff yes that is possible